# Button back ionic disappears

Tags: android, ios, navigation, ionic-framework

In navigation button often it disappears, maybe it's because I'm redirecting bad, although I think it would be weird because sometimes if it appears and sometimes simply not seen. That confuses the user much of the application and I still can not find solution to this, this happens on both iOS and Android. The way the button position is as follows:

```
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-android-arrow-back"></i></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

$ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false).text(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Some more code would be helpful, but the back button only appears as you go deeper into the $ionicHistory stack. When you switch between tabs or between menu items, this history stack is reset so you wont get a back button in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [defaultHref](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/blob/main/angular/src/directives/navigation/ion-back-button.ts#L14) property helped me:

```
<ion-back-button [defaultHref]="defaultHref"></ion-back-button>
```